# The best model, according to both AIC and BIC, contains only a non significant term

Tags: r, model-comparison

Id like to know how is it possible that the best model (m6), based on AIC and BIC values, can have a non significant term whereas the second best model(m5) has a signficant term.

I have the following competing models list:

```
m1=gls(Area_Km2~size+cent_Latitude+PCptail+pwingbilltar,corMartins(1,phy=ctree),data = c)
m2=gls(Area_Km2~size+cent_Latitude+PCptail,corMartins(1,phy=ctree),data = c)
m3=gls(Area_Km2~size+cent_Latitude,corMartins(1,phy=ctree),data = c)
m4=gls(Area_Km2~size,corMartins(1,phy=ctree),data = c)
m5=gls(Area_Km2~PCptail,corMartins(1,phy=ctree),data = c)
m6=gls(Area_Km2~cent_Latitude,corMartins(1,phy=ctree),data = c)
m7=gls(Area_Km2~pwingbilltar,corMartins(1,phy=ctree),data = c)
```

Here is model comparison

```
   Model df      AIC      BIC    logLik   Test  L.Ratio p-value
m1     1  7 147.2775 157.9620 -66.63873                        
m2     2  6 139.4866 148.8187 -63.74331 1 vs 2 5.790838  0.0161
m3     3  5 133.3334 141.2510 -61.66672 2 vs 3 4.153191  0.0416
m4     4  4 130.7749 137.2186 -61.38746 3 vs 4 0.558517  0.4549
m5     5  4 127.0635 133.5072 -59.53175                        
m6     6  4 125.1006 131.5443 -58.55029                        
m7     7  4 132.4542 138.8979 -62.22711
```

here goes m6

```
 Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: Area_Km2 ~ cent_Latitude 
  Data: c 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
   125.1006 131.5442 -58.55029

Correlation Structure: corMartins
 Formula: ~1  
 Parameter estimate(s):
alpha 
    1 

Coefficients:
               Value Std.Error    t-value p-value
(Intercept)    0.4940905 0.1730082  2.8558795  0.0070
cent_Latitude -0.1592109 0.1726268 -0.9222837  0.3624

 Correlation: 
          (Intr)
cent_Latitude -0.158

Standardized residuals:
   Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-1.3270048 -0.7088524 -0.2828898  0.4672255  2.2203523 

Residual standard error: 1.066911 
Degrees of freedom: 39 total; 37 residual
```

here goes m5

```
Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: Area_Km2 ~ PCptail 
  Data: c 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  127.0635 133.5072 -59.53175

Correlation Structure: corMartins
 Formula: ~1 
 Parameter estimate(s):
alpha 
    1 

Coefficients:
             Value  Std.Error   t-value p-value
(Intercept) 0.19752329 0.20158500 0.9798512  0.3335
PCptail     0.01925621 0.00851536 2.2613499  0.0297

 Correlation: 
        (Intr)
PCptail -0.595

Standardized residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-1.3416127 -0.6677304 -0.2467510  0.3198370  2.3339127 

Residual standard error: 1.01147 
Degrees of freedom: 39 total; 37 residual
```

Comment: What are you doing this in?

Comment: sorry, im doing this in R. didnt thought that was important.

Comment: I know nothing of R - it's always worth tagging a question with the language you're using, as it will be highlighted to those that flag that as an "interesting" tag

Comment: thought it appeared in the flag, you know is there a way to pass this question to crossvalidated? wonder it might have more interest in that directory.thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fitting the model using `method = "REML"` which is the restricted likelihood. It does not always follow that the maximized likelihood under REML will be close to the likelihood under unrestricted ML. Set `method = "ML"` and see if that fixes the "problem" with AIC/BIC.

Comment: Many thanks Iacobus! Indeed, using ML gives the renders the lowest AIC to the first model now for 5 AIC units and detects several significant relationships. I see nonetheless other problems that ill comment in my answer to jhoward.

Comment: As i need to flag one answer as the right one, i will mark this one because it apparently solved the initial proposed problem. The answer from jlhoward was nonetheless really helpful for completeness and other reasons. thanks to both again.

Answer (score 4):

There are at least two things going on here. First, it is not meaningful to assert that the model with the lowest AIC is the "best" model. For a set of models with different AIC, the relative probability that the i<sup>th</sup> model is better than the model with the lowest AIC is given by: (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion), and references cited therein):

> L = exp[ ( AIC<sub>min</sub> - AIC<sub>i</sub> ) / 2 ]

So, comparing `m5` and `m6`:

> L = exp[ (125.1006 - 127.0635) / 2 ] = 0.374

Or, there is a 37% chance that `m5` is in fact the better model. The point is that there is not a significant difference between an AIC of 125.2 and an AIC of 127, so you cannot say the `m6` is "best". Both models do about equally well.

So why is `cent_Latitude` insignificant in `m6`? A p-value > 0.05 means that the effect of `cent_Latitude` on the response is small compared to the error in the response. This could happen because the true effect size is 0, or it could happen because the effect size, combined with the range in `cent_latitude` results in an effect on the response which is small compared to the error in the response. You can see this in the following, which uses made-up data and creates the same effect yor are seeing with your real data.

Suppose the the response variable actually depends on both `cent_Latitude` and `PCptail`. In `m6`, variability in response due to the effect of `PCptail` is counted towards the "error" in the model, reducing the calculated significance of `cent_Latitude`. On the other hand, in `m5` the variability in response due to the effect of `cent_Latitude` is counted toward the error, reducing the significance of `PCptail`. If the effect sizes, compared to the true error, are just right you can get this effect, as shown below. Note that this is one of the reasons it is *not recommended* to compare non-nested models using a single statistic (like AIC, or RSQ, or even F).

```
library(nlme)
set.seed(1)
# for simplicity, use un-correlated predictors
c <- data.frame(PCptail=sample(seq(0,10,.1),length(seq)),
                cent_Latitude=sample(seq(0,1,.01),length(seq)))
# response depends on both predictors
c$Area <- 1 + .01*c$PCptail +.1*c$cent_Latitude + rnorm(nrow(c),0,1)
m6 <- gls(Area~cent_Latitude,c)
m5 <- gls(Area~PCptail,c)
summary(m6)
# Generalized least squares fit by REML
#   Model: Area ~ cent_Latitude 
#   Data: c 
#        AIC      BIC    logLik
#   288.5311 296.3165 -141.2656
# 
# Coefficients:
#                    Value Std.Error   t-value p-value
# (Intercept)    1.1835936 0.1924341  6.150645  0.0000
# cent_Latitude -0.1882202 0.3324754 -0.566118  0.5726
# ...
summary(m5)
# Generalized least squares fit by REML
#   Model: Area ~ PCptail 
#   Data: c 
#        AIC      BIC    logLik
#   289.2713 297.0566 -141.6356
# 
# Coefficients:
#                 Value  Std.Error  t-value p-value
# (Intercept) 0.7524261 0.18871413 3.987121  0.0001
# PCptail     0.0674115 0.03260484 2.067530  0.0413
# ...
```

So how to deal with this? Well, have you looked at the residuals plots for all these models? Have you looked at the Q-Q plots? Leverage plots? Generally, all other thins being equal, I would pick the model with the more significant parameters, assuming the residuals were random and normally distributed, and the none of the data points had unusually high leverage.

Comment: Fantastic answer jhoward. I tried to use your hint but gave me the following error:

Comment: I now used"ML"estimation according to iacobus and I tried to use your hint to assess the new difference in models. It though gave me the following error: 'Error in exp[(149.9908 - 155.2992)/2] : 
  object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable'. The liliefors test says the residuals are not normal and the relationships among residuals are quite heterocedastic and probably non linear. I think I need to transform my variables before re-testing.

Comment: That equation wa not meant to  be an R expression. Replace the square brackets with parens.

Comment: Also, do you have to use gls? I don't know your dataset, but a generalized linear model (glm) might be more appropriate.